# is there a simple way to use svg-edit as inline wysiwyg editor?

Tags: svg-edit

I see it is [used in separate window by blue griffon](http://bluegriffon.org/public/info/svg.png), but is it possible to make it edit the svg in place?

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could open svg-edit.html and remove any html, head, and body tags and move the content of the page to your page and then load js/css resources on your page.

Is there a specific need to place it inline though? You can still interact with SVG-Edit even while it's in an iframe if you need to. For example, to get the SVG content that the user is editing, you would use

```
var svgedit = window.frames[0];
svgedit.svgCanvas.svgCanvasToString();
```

Comment: the specific need at the time was the client requirement to edit svg in-place

Comment: I didn't notice how old the question was. Lol